# Boxplot incompleto en R

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que dice lo siguiente:

> Haga un boxplot de la media de edad de los municipios. ¿Cuál es el
> municipio con la media de edad más alta?

Y estas son las columnas que se utilizan:

```
municipi = código postal del municipio y nombre del municipio,
edat = edad media de los habitantes del municipio,
pobl= número de habitantes del municipio,
prov = provincia a la que pertenece el municipio.
```

En R hago el boxplot asi:

```
boxplot(temp$edat)
```

Donde `temp` es la variable donde almaceno los datos del .csv y `edat` la media de los municipios. Esto me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me piden que nombre **el municipio** con la media de edad mas alta. Entonces intente lo siguiente:

```
boxplot(temp$edat ~ temp$municipi)
```

Y me lo devuelve de esta forma, que para mi es ilegible, además de que no muestra todos los municipios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Hay alguna otra forma de resolver el ejercicio?** O al menos saber cual es el municipio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si solamente tienes un dato de edad por municipio (la media), el primer boxplot está bien hecho. En cuanto al nombre del municipio con mayor edad media, lo puedes obtener así:

```
temp$municipi[which.max(temp$edat)]
```